# Measurability of functions - Is $f$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Suppose that $([0,3], \sigma([0,3]))$ and $([0,\infty], \mathcal{A})$, with $\mathcal{A} =\{\emptyset, [0,\infty]\}$. Using $f: [0,3] \to [0, \infty]$ such that $f(x)=x^2$, then is $f$ measurable?

I am having trouble identifying if the function $f$ is measurable. However, my theory is that it is not measurable, but dont know how to prove it or why it is true (that it is not measurable)

Comment: Compute the two sets $\{x \in [0,3] : f(x) \in \varnothing\}$ and $\{x \in [0,3] : f(x) \in [0,\infty]\}$.  Do those sets belong to $\sigma([0,3])$?  Include your attempt in the question, otherwise the question may be closed.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, but is $\sigma ([0,3]) = \{\emptyset, [0,3]\}$?

Comment: Uh, is $\sigma([0,3])$ supposed to be the ... Borel algebra? Lebesgue measurable algebra? Actually the answer doesn't matter, $f$ will be measurable regardless of what $\sigma([0,3])$ is

Comment: This is in the same spirit as the fact that all functions *into* a space endowed with the trivial topology are continuous